# How to retrive last enty in ACCESS database using C# via OleDB with sql commands

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

Again me with me form base program (with visual C# 2010)
After getting most of my program to work I started adding some small "extras"

Here is the problem: when I add a new item, I want to open a MessageBox and write the id of the new item.

**Table = Item, field = item_id**

Tried using:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST(item_id) FROM Item";
OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    id = dr["item_id"].ToString();
}
```

Here is the full function:

```
public void ItemInsert(string name,string creator,string publishing,string itemType,string genere, string year)
{
    string id ="";
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Item  (item_name, creator_name,publishing_name,item_type,genre,year_publication,location) VALUES (@item_name, @creator_name,@publishing_name,@item_type,@genre,@year_publication,@location);";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_name", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creator_name", creator);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publishing_name",publishing);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_type", itemType);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genre",genere);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year_publication",year);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", 0);//location=0 when in library

    con.Open(); // open the connection
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //get item id
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST(item_id) FROM Item";
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        id = dr["item_id"].ToString();
    }

    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Item ID : " + id+"","Added new item");
}
```

Comment: how do i get the id of the last item i made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT LAST(item_id) FROM Item";
```

With:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
```

Comment: tried it... got error on : id = dr["item_id"].ToString();
 error is: indexoutofrangeexception was unhandled, item_id

Comment: `dr[0].ToString();` Of course, you must have an autonumber, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the "IDENTITY" stuff has not worked (maybe because the field was not **PK** or AI). It was always the id "0"

i used this query:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 item_id FROM Item ORDER BY item_id DESC";
```

*Note that the "TOP 1" is equal to other sql-dialect's "LIMIT 1"*

so in short, without setting further cmd options:

```
object scalarInt = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 item_id FROM Item ORDER BY item_id DESC", con).ExecuteScalar();
int lastItemId = (int?) scalarInt ?? 0;
```

where the 0 at the end of the last line is the default return value, if there are no entries yet. you may use 1 as database Id's typically start with 1.